# Titanium IOS7 - Tabs colors (TabGroup)

Tags: tabs, ios7, titanium

How I get a TabGroup like this in IOS7:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ht3rl9qje4kspb2/foto.png

with full color in background, another color in selected tab and white icon (no default gray) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select background color for selected and unselected tabs you can use those properties:

- [activeTabBackgroundColor](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup-property-activeTabBackgroundColor)
- [backgroundColor](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup-property-backgroundColor)

Color of the icon is used from file, which you can edit in your image editor.

Comment: Do you try this in IOS 7 ?